# Swap internal HDD with SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata

I'm planning to swap my internal HDD with an SSD. My PC says my HDD is SATAII, is it possible to just plug in a SATAIII SSD and use the HDD as an external drive with a SATA/USB cable?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes of course it is.  SATAIII is backwards compatible with SATAII

Comment: Unless this is a laptop, you can probably keep the HDD and SSD both internal; You will probably find that an SSD fills up quickly!

Comment: Yes it's a laptop. So now you'll get it why I want to swap the drives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use the Sata3 SSD.

Yes you can use the HDD as an external drive via sata or usb assuming it receives power somehow, the most common way to do this is to purchase an enclosure for it.

Comment: and this was downvoted because?

Comment: yea, why did I just get downvoted for this. Care to comment?

Comment: I guess somebody was too hardcore to buy an enclosure for an external drive.

Comment: I've found a sata/usb adapter for a few bucks that does it for me. sata is powered by 2 usb's one for data one for power.